# Problems Repackaging Mozilla Addon Builder Extension Files

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Have made quite a bit of progress in my quest to figuring out the Mozilla extension platform, but am still struggling with a few issues.. Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction once again :)

Ok, so here is the issue... I have been messing around with the online addon builder app here: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/

Great, this seems to be working ok for testing simple addons. But it includes so much extra junk - stuff I am not using and don't need there.

Now when I download the .xpi file, rename it to .zip, and extract it to work on the files, when I repackage it to a zip -> xpi, Firefox tells me the package is corrupt when I try to install.

I have deduced that this is because the package is "signed" or something, and when I repackage it myself this is not happening.

Whatever. This is getting ridiculous...

So I want to use the SDK to work locally, and then just include the SDK in the directory somehow. But it looks like I need to install python and run something in order to generate some files first blah blah blah.... are you joking me? I can't just code my app, then include the SDK files?

QUESTION:

How can I create my basic addon/extension with the online Addon Builder, then edit the files locally, repackage it, and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ons created with the SDK currently aren't signed (see [bug 613618](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=613618)). There are a bunch of SHA256 checksums in the package manifest but nothing is verifying them (maybe they are meant for verification by external tools, I don't know). So this is not the problem you are experiencing.

Most likely issue is that when you repacked the ZIP file you didn't keep the directory structure. The `install.rdf` file needs to be at the top level of the package, not in some subdirectory. You can check it with the `unzip -l mypackage.xpi` - it should list `install.rdf` without any directory name.

Generally, I would advise against manipulating the XPI files. By removing unused modules you might be able to save 100 kB in download size, most likely less - somebody installing your add-on will not even notice the difference in download size. Modules that aren't used have zero impact on performance of your add-on. But you risk removing something that is actually used, maybe in a non-obvious way. And once AMO starts [repacking SDK add-ons automatically](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2011/10/04/add-on-sdk-repacks-proposal/) they will replace your add-on by the standard package anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation once again! :)

Yes, the problem was I was changing the directory structure and removing stuff. I stopped doing that I ended up installing the SDK and am actually really enjoying developing with the shell to debug. It was just a lot more setup than I'm used to for simple web app type implementations.